# jQuery Selecting based on a data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have several input elements, that only differ on their data- attribute.

```
<input name="country" data-action="buy"/>
<input name="country" data-action="sell"/>
```

I'm trying to get the value that the user entered into the input with a "buy" data-

What's the selector I should use?

```
$("input[name=country] ????").val()
```

(There is a reason they have the same name and no id that's not related to the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `data-action="buy"` also as an attribute selector

```
$('input[name="country"][data-action="buy"]').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[data-action='buy']").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='country']").filter(i) {
  return $(this).data('action') == 'buy';
}).val();
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer, thanks. What's the advantage over a plain selector?

Comment: I don't know that there is an advantage but it provides a little practice with the `.filter()` method.